# Which of the following is valid first order formula?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Which of the following is a valid first order formula ?

(Here $α$ and $β$ are first order formula with $x$ as their only free variable)

- $[((∀x)[α] ⇒ (∀x)[β])] ⇒ [(∀x)[α ⇒ β]]$
- $[(∀x)[α]] ⇒ [(∃x)[α ∧ β]]$
- $[((∀x)[α ∨ β] ⇒ (∃x)[α])] ⇒ [(∀x)[α]]$
- $[(∀x)[α ⇒ β]] ⇒ [((∀x)[α]) ⇒ (∀x)[β])]$

---

I tried by taking $α$ as $0=0$ and $β$ as $0=1$, but still not getting.

Is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: Not every valid FOL formula is a tautology of prop calculus (consider e.g. $\forall x (x=x)$. Thus, the truth-table method does not work (in general) to show validity.

Comment: What "kind of proof" are you asked to use ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Any proof, as we just have to check the validity. Can you explain the 2nd line of thee question ?

Comment: For the second one, try with $(x \ge 0)$ for $\alpha$ and $(x < 0)$ as $\beta$ in the domain $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, from your example, 2nd one is not valid .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what I used as  $α$ and $β$. Is that wrong ?

Comment: For 1st and 4th, see the post [which-of-the-following-is-a-valid-first-order-formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241032/which-of-the-following-is-a-valid-first-order-formula).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Just a doubt. Here I have $α$ and $β$ and in that example, it is using $p(x)$ and $g(x)$ . Will there be any difference ?As I think $α$ and $β$ don't depend on $x$ but other one depends on $x$ .

Comment: You have written "Here $α$  and $β$ are first order formula with $x$ as their only free variable". Thus thei are $α(x)$  and $β(x)$...

Answer (score 0):

In the given question the last point is the valid first order formula:

We can prove this by using **law of contradiction** and **Rule of Inference** (Modus Ponens specifically). The TT or boolean alzebra methods will be a bit difficult to apply in case of Predicate Logic, therefore your method of taking α as 0 = 0, β as 0 = 1 would be a little herculean.

**Proof**:

> Let the consider the LHS to be **true** i.e.
>   [(∀x)[α⇒β]] is **true**
>
> which means
>
> α1 => β1, α2 => β2, α3=> β3, ..., αn => βn are **true**. Now we have to prove the RHS to be **false**
>
> Also, in implication we can write **A => (B => C) as (A ^ B) => C**
>
> Therefore we can write, [(∀x)[α⇒β]]⇒[((∀x)[α]) as ***[(∀x)[α⇒β]] `^` [((∀x)[α])***.
>
> Now using **Rule of detachment (Modus Ponens)** i.e. If **(p => q and p) => q** 
>   we can prove that  **[(∀x)[α⇒β]] `^` [((∀x)[α]) => (∀x)[β])**.
>
> Note, here if we want to make RHS **false** by any means; we will not be able to. Therefore; **~F = T (Proof by contradiction)**

Also, notice the first Option is the converse of the 4th option and is not valid. And other two options are vaguely out of order.